# What does 'the' in 'the someone' mean?

Tags: meaning, definite-article

There are lots of examples where the definite article is used with the pronoun 'someone', for example:

> I never knew you were **the someone** waiting for me. [(Source.)](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/edsheeran/perfect.html)
>   How about a little something special for **the someone** who truly deserves it?
>   For all creative people we suggest to place **the someone** works (poems, stories, songs, figures, an art photo, etc.) on this site.

I wonder what does 'the' mean in contexts like these and are there any other cases when we can use the definite article before a pronoun? Are these examples grammatically correct?

Comment: The Ed Sheeran lyrics example is effectively "romantic poetry" -  in which context we often conventionally assume everyone has ***one specific "soulmate"*** that they're searching for (or have found, depending on whether it's a blues song or a love song). And *something special for the someone who truly deserves it* is more an example of "playing with language" than a reflection of normal English syntax. Finally, *place the someone works* is syntactic gibberish - it's effectively a "form filling" exercise where you're expected to write the actual artist's name instead of ***the someone***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Someone" normally refers to a *specific* person (even if you haven't identified them) so normally it would not require the definite article. For example: "*There is someone in my house*".

If your sentence used a less specific word like "person" then you would expect the definite article:

> I never knew you were **the person** waiting for me.

Your sentence doesn't really make sense out of context, but it suggests that the speaker has already referred to an *unidentified* person as "somebody", and then gone on to link that to the person they are now speaking to.

For example:

> My boss said somebody was waiting for me. I never knew *you* were the someone.

Comment: Thank you! But is this case the only one? And is it grammatically correct and may it be used in a neutral context?

Comment: No, without any context it is not correct. I have suggested one possible context where it may be understood. I don't know what you mean by "neutral context".

Comment: Sorry, I've misused this term. I meant _neutral style, register_.

Answer (score 2):

**Someone** in this context isn't just any someone, but **that special** someone.

There are several indefinite pronouns you can add the definite article to, like one, many and few.

E.g. the Marine Corps' recruiting slogan,

> "The Few. The Proud. The Marines."